# Slider need animation on timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="sp" style="background: blue;">akjdfalfkdj</div>
        <div class="sp" style="background: yellow;">akjdfautlfkdkjkhkj</div>
        <div class="sp" style="background: green;" >akjdfalfkdiyukjkhkj</div>
        <div class="sp" style="background: red;">akjdfalfkdkkljjkhkj</div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="button-previous">prev</div>
<div id="button-next">next</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slider-wrapper {width:500px; height:200px;}
#slider {width:500px; height:200px; position:relative;}
.sp {width:500px; height:200px; position:absolute;}

#nav {margin-top:20px; width:100%;}
#button-previous {float:left;}
#button-next {float:right;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sp').first().addClass('active');
$('.sp').hide();    
$('.active').show();

    $('#button-next').click(function(){

    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                   if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();


    });

       $('#button-previous').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
           if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
        }
           else{
    $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
           }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();
    }); 
});
```

I have the above jquery slider all i need to have a timeout function which the slider slides automatically and as well i need it to slide according to the prev and next buttons. Thanks in advance

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HsEne/15/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Use `clearInterval(tId)` to stop and `run()` to start again if you want to pause when next/prev is clicked

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/npq27/)

```
var tId;
function run() {
  tId=setInterval(function() { $("#button-next").click()},1000);
}
$(function() {
    $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
    $('.sp').hide();
    $('.active').show();
    $sp = $(".sp");
    $('.nav').click(function () {
        var which = this.id.replace("button-", ""),
            next = which == "next",
            $oldActive = $('.active');
        if (next) {
            if ($oldActive.index()==$sp.length-1) {
                $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
            } else {
                $oldActive.next().addClass('active');
            }
        } else {
            if ($oldActive.index()==0) {
                $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
            } else {
                $oldActive.prev().addClass('active');
            }
        }
        $oldActive.removeClass('active');
        $('.sp').fadeOut();
        $('.active').fadeIn();
    });
    run();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To use the timeout function goes like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
//your function you want to timeout
},1000);
```

1000 milliseconds = 1 second

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use the jQuery.animate function. Something like this:

```
$(".active").animate({width:"100%"},750);
```

This assumes that the sliders have a default css property of width: 0%.

Edit: new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qnM3x/1/

Comment: Only the first slide slides i need it to loop automatically and i also need my next and prev button to work any suggestions.

Comment: any alternate for my jquery

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. Only the first slide is animating? "and i also need my next and prev button to work" --When you click on the buttons they make the slider slide, right? Should they do something else?

Comment: I might recommend using a prebuilt slider/carousel if you want to show off photos. Something like this: http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-slider.html